# search button in search keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios4, uikeyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a search bar and on clicking the search bar the keyboard pops up. On pressing the search button on search keyboard the keyboard should hide. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to call the resignFirstResponder method

```
-(IBAction)ButtonClick
{
    [txtview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

there are several answers to this question on StackOverFlow. Just search.